# A pattern matching an expression that doesn't end with specific sequence

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I need a regex pattern which matches such strings that DO NOT end with such a sequence:
`\.[A-z0-9]{2,}`
by which I mean the examined string must not have at its end a sequence of a dot and then two or more alphanumeric characters.
For example, a string
`/home/patryk/www`
and also
`/home/patryk/www/`
should match desired pattern and
`/home/patryk/images/DSC002.jpg` should not.
I suppose this has something to do with lookarounds (look aheads) but still I have no idea how to make it.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you really mean "match (full/entire) string" or "match substring"?

Comment: I mean to match the entire string, i.e.
`/home/me/public/`
is matched while
`/home/me/images/DSC001.jpg`
is not. This actually reveals what is my purpose but still I want to know that.

Comment: Could you please also add a bunch of test strings and matches?

Comment: Is it possible to rely on the last forward slash?

Comment: Well, I would like both with the slash at the end and without it to match the pattern. But say it is not, does this simplify the solution?

Comment: @patryk I think Asad doesn't mean that the string ends in `/` but that there is at least one `/` in the string.

Comment: I guess that with the word 'last' he actually meant the slash that the string would end with. Anyway if your interpretation is right, then my answer is no, the string might not contain any slashes aswell.

Answer (score 2):

**Old Answer**

You can use a negative lookbehind at the end if your regex flavor supports it:

```
^.*+(?<!\.\w{2,})$
```

This will match a string that has an end anchor *not* preceded by the icky sequence you don't want.

Note that as m.buettner has pointed out, this uses an indefinite length lookbehind, which is  a feature unique to .NET

---

**New Answer**

After a bit of digging around, however, I've found that variable length look-*aheads* are pretty widely supported, so here is a version that uses those:

```
^(?:(?!\.\w{2,}$).)++$
```

In a comment on an answer, you have stated you wanted to not match strings with forward slashes at the end, which is accomplished by simply adding a forward slash to the lookahead.

```
^(?:(?!(\.\w{2,}|/)$).)++$
```

Note that I am using `\w` for succinctness, but it lets underscores through. If this is important, you could replace it with `[^\W_]`.

Comment: This will only work in .NET, because of the variable-length lookbehind.

Comment: I guess .NET is probably clever enough to optimize that by itself, but if not you could avoid some backtracking by either moving the `$` in front of the lookbehind, or even better by making the `.*` [possessive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) like `.*#`.

Comment: Good idea, added. I'm not sure how moving the `$` in front of the lookbehind would improve performance though.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo there. Possessive quantifiers are `.*+`. If you use this then you don't need the other optimization. It would only be relevant if the engine doesn't optimize that anyway (which I doubt). Then if the lookbehind fails, the engine would start to backtrack the `.*` and would try to match the two zero-width assertions at every position in the string. And of course, it's cheaper to check for `$` first (which always fails) instead of trying the negative lookbehind.

Comment: @m.buettner Thanks for your input :) I have updated the answer with a more universal solution.

Comment: I like the idea, but it won't work unless you include `$` into the lookahead (consider `some.thing/likethis`; the lookahead will fail once you reach the period)

Answer (score 1):

Asad's version is very convenient, but only .NET's regex engine supports variable-length lookbehinds (which is one of the many reasons why every regex question should include the language or tool used).

We can reduce this to a fixed-length lookbehind (which is supported in most engines except for JavaScrpit) if we think about the possible cases which should match. That would be either one or zero letters/digits at the end (whether preceded by `.` or not) or two or more letters/digits that are not preceded by a dot.

```
^.*(?:(?<![a-zA-Z0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]?|(?<![a-zA-Z0-9.])[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,})$
```

Comment: Nice! The variable length lookbehind solution is no more than a curiosity it would seem.

Comment: @Asad I would definitely recommend it if .NET is used, since it is much easier to read and understand. But it's quite a restriction on the applicability. But maybe you're lucky and the OP does use .NET ;)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
^(?:[^.]+|\.(?![A-Za-z0-9]{2,}$))+$
```

It alternates between matching one or more of anything except a dot, or a dot if it's not followed by two or more alphanumeric characters and the end of the string.

**EDIT:** Upgrading it to meet the new requirement is just more of the same:

```
^(?:[^./]+|/(?=.)|\.(?![A-Za-z0-9]{2,}$))+$
```

Breaking that down, we have:

- `[^./]+`          # one or more of any characters except `.` or `/`
- `/(?=.)`          # a slash, as long as there's at least one character following it
- `\.(?![A-Za-z0-9]{2,}$)` # a dot, unless it's followed by two or more alphanumeric characters followed by the end of the string

---

On another note: **`[A-z]` is an error.**  It matches all the uppercase and lowercase ASCII letters, but it also matches the characters `[`, `]`, `^`, `_`, backslash and backtick, whose code points happen to lie between `Z` and `a`.

Comment: I've been trying to find out how to upgrade your pattern so is doesn't match strings with the forward slash at the end either but didn't make it. It is true that this is not exactly what I asked for in my first question. Is there an easy way to rewrite this pattern like that?

Comment: Check my upgraded answer.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much what I wanted to do. Thank all of you very much for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Variable length look behinds are rarely supported, but you don't need one:

```
^.*(?<!\.[A-z0-9][A-z0-9]?)$
```

Comment: @Asad It is. But it is supported by more engines than your version, because it consists of only two possible lengths (some engines allow variable-length if there is only a finite number of possible lengths). But yes, this should be noted. In addition this will accept `some.jpg`, which is more of a problem.

Comment: The obvious-maximum-length rule is a Java innovation, not supported by any other flavor.  So this regex would be valid in Java as well as in .NET, JGSoft and D, which support unrestricted lookbehinds.  (But see the note in my answer regarding `[A-z]`.)